# How to load a CSS data-theme before the initial page loads to prevent flickering between Themes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have a data-theme that contains **a lot** of modifications to the original CSS theme.  I already have a toggle switch working and I save it to localStorage so it can be remembered.  However, whenever I go between pages with the dark-theme already enabled, it loads the original theme first but applies the dark-theme **after** the whole page has loaded.  I want this transition between pages to be seamless.

I am using Node.js and express for the web application.

My data-theme modification is about 200 lines long.  Here's a short snippet of the data-theme:

```
[data-theme="dark"] html {
  background-color: #111111 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .bg-light {
  background-color: #333 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .bg-white {
  background-color: #000 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .bg-black {
  background-color: #eee !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .topbar {
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
  color: #2a1e37 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[data-theme="dark"] .btn {
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
  border: 1px solid #2196f3 !important;
  color: #2a1e37 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

etc.  It goes on for most of my elements.

**An example of my problem is shown in this short gif:**

https://gyazo.com/d53e12b7b5ea5215659a59a67639ba37

Currently, I have a script that determines whether or not to apply the dark theme or light theme in the  tag.

```
function initTheme() {
      console.log("initTheme() invoked!");
    var darkThemeSelected =
      localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") !== null &&
      localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") === "dark";

    darkThemeSelected
      ? document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark") 
      : document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");

    if (darkThemeSelected){
      document.getElementById("darkModeText").innerHTML=`Turn Lights On`;
      document.getElementById("darkModeIcon").className="zmdi zmdi-brightness-5";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("darkModeText").innerHTML=`Turn Lights Off`;
      document.getElementById("darkModeIcon").className="zmdi zmdi-brightness-3";
    }
  }
```

As you can see though, I am modifying some elements that do not exist yet since they exist in the body.  How can I achieve the dark-theme prior to loading it?  I am using node.js and express.

Comment: Is that even beneficial? In CSS, the last rules wins if they have the same specifity.

Assuming your Express server is also serving the HTML, you'd need to switch the `<link rel="stylesheet" />` tag accordingly. For this to work better, it would help to store the preference of theme (light/dark) in a cookie on the client side and read it with Express (cookies are always send along requests).

Comment: Is what beneficial?  is localStorage not a cookie?

Comment: No, localStorage remains on the client (but survives closing of the browser - unlike sessionStorage).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable transition when initializing page

```js
var element = document.getElementById('body');

function toggleTransition() {
  element.classList.toggle('dark');
}

function toggleNoTransition() {
  element.classList.add('disabled-transition');
  element.classList.toggle('dark');
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.remove('disabled-transition');
  }, 300)
}
```

```css
.body {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.dark.body {
  background: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.dark .btn {
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
  border: 1px solid #2196f3 !important;
  color: #2a1e37 !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.disabled-transition,
.disabled-transition * {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="body" class="body">
  <button onClick="toggleTransition()" class="btn">toggle tranisition</button>
  <button onClick="toggleNoTransition()" class="btn">toggle no-tranisition</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think transitions is the problem.  It's the loading of the css-theme prior to the initial page load.

Comment: Are you sure that initialization dark theme is before loading?
In your example, initializing a dark theme through javascript, but a light theme is rendered before javascript

Comment: I think the light theme is rendered before javascript because I do the changing of the themes client side.  My question is how to make it so that the dark-mode theme can be rendered first

Comment: Insert <script> with initTheme into the HTML page (without src), class with theme will be added before initial main styles